# Change customer store _id and created_from

Tags: magento

I need to change store_id and created_from of my customers.
I've try import store view with dataflow with this column (website base, store it) and without column with store view default set in dataflow import profile, all without success.

So, how i can change it in import or after import.
I need that for manage newsletter list destination in mailchimp sync.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve it.
i don't use Dataflow import/export magento base.
I've install amazing extension "amartinez_customimportexport" all export/import work directly in db and all work fine.